# VMware Kernel modules update in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, 15.04, vmware

[image]

I was prompted to update the Vmware Player and so I did.

It downloaded and installed perfectly but when I ran it for the first time after the update a prompts appear to me with the saying it several modules to be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.

The required module is `3.16.0-44-generic` and I searched the Ubuntu Software Center but did not find anything.

How can I overcome this problem?

Useful commands:

```
# uname -r
3.16.0-44-generic

# apt-cache policy linux-headers-generic
linux-headers-generic:
  Installed: 3.19.0.39.38
  Candidate: 3.19.0.42.41
  Version table:
     3.19.0.42.41 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.19.0.39.38 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.19.0.15.14 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I would assume that this is only part of the error message.  Can you copy and paste the entire error message into your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I updated the question with the following with that is prompted when I ran it. Thanks

Comment: This is strange. [15.04 uses a 3.19 kernel](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-headers-generic&searchon=names), not 3.16. What's the output of `uname -r` and `apt-cache policy linux-headers-generic`?

Comment: @muru First command:  `3.16.0-44-generic` and second: `linux-headers-generic:
  Installed: 3.19.0.39.38
  Candidate: 3.19.0.42.41
  Version table:
     3.19.0.42.41 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.19.0.39.38 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.19.0.15.14 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: Did you upgrade from 14.10? When you reboot, what kernel choices are you given in the GRUB menu?

Comment: @muru I think yes. The first version I used in this notebook was 14.04 then I was keeping the upgrading until this version (15.10). I do not choose any because It boots automatically. The VMWare Player were working great until I got the popup yesterday asking me to update the software.

Comment: If you issue the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` does your system indicate that some packages have been help back?

Comment: @CharlesGreen `apt-get update` does not give any useful output but the `apt-get upgrade` gives that http://pastie.org/10655394 ps: ran in sudo mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your kernel has not updated properly with your transition to Ubuntu 15.04 - I would encourage you to make a backup of your data first, and then issue the command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

After a reboot, you should be running the 3.19 kernel.  You should check to ensure that your kernel version and your header version match; you may also need to execute

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: Thanks Charles Green. It worked with no problem.